# Why is my input button not doing my actions (ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a `<asp:Button>` button in a `<form>` and it is "connected" to the C# code. My C# code should redirect users to the homepage (Homepage.html). Something like this:

```
protected void Inlog_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Homepage.html");
}
```

But, instead redirecting to the Homepage, the action will reload the page with: `Login.aspx?ctl00=Inloggen`.

Why is the app "ignoring" my written C# action?

Here is the whole HTML code

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="OSGS_KANTINE_WEB.login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=" j-feature-js j-feature-no-touch j-feature-opacity j-feature-csstransitions" lang="nl-NL"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://u.jimdo.com/">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//assets.jimstatic.com/">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://image.jimcdn.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://www.google-analytics.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://u.jimdo.com/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//assets.jimstatic.com/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://image.jimcdn.com" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.google-analytics.com" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta property="st:section" content="">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="app">
<meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="588950703">
<meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="588950703">
<meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="com.jimdo">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="logo_lyceum.ico" />
    
<link rel="canonical" href="http://osgs-kantine-site-design.jimdo.com/login-1/">
    <style>
        html,body{margin:0}.hidden{display:none}.n{padding:5px}#cc-website-title a {text-decoration: none}.cc-m-image-align-1{text-align:left}.cc-m-image-align-2{text-align:right}.cc-m-image-align-3{text-align:center}
.subbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.subbutton span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.subbutton span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.subbutton:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.subbutton:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #f4511e;
}
input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none;
}

input[type=password]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #f4511e;
}
</style>


        <link href="https://u.jimdo.com/www400/o/s2080dbef3339dc21/layout/dm_0daae465c1d01048b40b213ad7efcc70/css/layout.css?t=1456656473" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="jimdo_layout_css">
<script src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WDBL3P&amp;l=_jimdoDataLayer" async=""></script><script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async=""></script><script src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WDBL3P&amp;l=_jimdoDataLayer" async=""></script><script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async=""></script><script>     /* <![CDATA[ */     /*!  loadCss [c]2014 @scottjehl, Filament Group, Inc.  Licensed MIT */     window.loadCSS = window.loadCss = function(e,n,t){var r,l=window.document,a=l.createElement("link");if(n)r=n;else{var i=(l.body||l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).childNodes;r=i[i.length-1]}var o=l.styleSheets;a.rel="stylesheet",a.href=e,a.media="only x",r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,n?r:r.nextSibling);var d=function(e){for(var n=a.href,t=o.length;t--;)if(o[t].href===n)return e.call(a);setTimeout(function(){d(e)})};return a.onloadcssdefined=d,d(function(){a.media=t||"all"}),a};     window.onloadCSS = function(n,o){n.onload=function(){n.onload=null,o&&o.call(n)},"isApplicationInstalled"in navigator&&"onloadcssdefined"in n&&n.onloadcssdefined(o)}     /* ]]> */ </script>     <script>
// <![CDATA[
onloadCSS(loadCss('//assets.jimstatic.com/web_unresponsive.css.16b9ae9aa4f337928af181600e98551e.css') , function() {
    this.id = 'jimdo_web_css';
});
// ]]>
</script><link media="all" href="//assets.jimstatic.com/web_unresponsive.css.16b9ae9aa4f337928af181600e98551e.css" rel="stylesheet"><link id="jimdo_web_css" media="all" href="//assets.jimstatic.com/web_unresponsive.css.16b9ae9aa4f337928af181600e98551e.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//assets.jimstatic.com/web_unresponsive.css.16b9ae9aa4f337928af181600e98551e.css" rel="preload" as="style">
<noscript>
<link href="//assets.jimstatic.com/web_unresponsive.css.16b9ae9aa4f337928af181600e98551e.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</noscript>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
        var jimdoData = {"isTestserver":false,"isLcJimdoCom":false,"isJimdoHelpCenter":false,"isProtectedPage":false,"cstok":"b7572c81c13157a7c0f12ff29ba267b86ecc2b30","cacheJsKey":"5142cd437b8c2d4dc78374d706a685d16d36a82e","cacheCssKey":"5142cd437b8c2d4dc78374d706a685d16d36a82e","cdnUrl":"\/\/assets.jimstatic.com\/","minUrl":"\/\/assets.jimstatic.com\/app\/cdn\/min\/file\/","authUrl":"https:\/\/a.jimdo.com\/","webPath":"http:\/\/osgs-kantine-site-design.jimdo.com\/","appUrl":"http:\/\/a.jimdo.com\/","webserver":"http:\/\/web403.jimdo.com\/","cmsLanguage":"nl_NL","isFreePackage":true,"mobile":false,"isDevkitTemplateUsed":true,"isTemplateResponsive":false,"websiteId":"s2080dbef3339dc21","pageId":2147754849,"packageId":1,"shop":{"deliveryTimeTexts":{"1":"Levertijd: 1-3 dagen","2":"Levertijd: 3-5 dagen","3":"Levertijd: 5-8 dagen"},"checkoutButtonText":"Naar de kassa","isReady":false,"currencyFormat":{"pattern":"\u00a4 #,##0.00;\u00a4 #,##0.00-","convertedPattern":"$ #,##0.00","symbols":{"GROUPING_SEPARATOR":".","DECIMAL_SEPARATOR":",","CURRENCY_SYMBOL":"\u20ac"}},"currencyLocale":"nl_NL"},"tr":{"gmap":{"searchNotFound":"Het ingevoerde adres kon niet worden gevonden of bestaat niet.","routeNotFound":"De route kon niet berekend worden. Mogelijke oorzaken: het vertrekadres is niet precies genoeg aangegeven of te ver van het aankomstadres verwijderd."},"shop":{"checkoutSubmit":{"next":"Volgende stap","wait":"Een moment geduld"},"paypalError":"Helaas is er iets verkeerd gegaan. Probeer het nog een keer!","cartBar":"Naar de winkelwagen","maintenance":"Deze webwinkel is tijdelijk helaas niet bereikbaar. Probeer het later nog eens.","addToCartOverlay":{"productInsertedText":"Het product is aan de winkelwagen toegevoegd.","continueShoppingText":"Verder winkelen","reloadPageText":"Opnieuw laden"},"notReadyText":"Het opzetten van deze webwinkel is nog niet volledig afgerond.","numLeftText":"Er zijn op dit moment niet meer dan {:num} exemplaren van dit artikel beschikbaar.","oneLeftText":"Er is helaas nog maar \u00e9\u00e9n exemplaar van dit product beschikbaar."},"common":{"timeout":"Er is een fout opgetreden. De door jou gekozen actie werd onderbroken. Probeer het later nog een keer."},"form":{"badRequest":"Er is een fout opgetreden. De invoer kon helaas niet verzonden worden. Probeer het later nog een keer!"}},"jQuery":"jimdoGen002","isJimdoMobileApp":false,"bgConfig":{"id":82641349,"type":"color","color":"rgb(255, 255, 255)"},"responsiveBreakpointLandscape":767,"responsiveBreakpointPortrait":480,"copyableHeadlineLinks":false};
    // ]]>
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="body cc-page j-m-flash-styles j-m-gallery-styles j-m-video-styles j-m-hr-styles j-m-header-styles j-m-text-styles j-m-emotionheader-styles j-m-htmlCode-styles j-m-rss-styles j-m-form-styles j-m-table-styles j-m-textWithImage-styles j-m-downloadDocument-styles j-m-imageSubtitle-styles j-m-flickr-styles j-m-googlemaps-styles j-m-blogSelection-styles j-m-comment-styles j-m-jimdo-styles j-m-profile-styles j-m-guestbook-styles j-m-promotion-styles j-m-twitter-styles j-m-hgrid-styles j-m-shoppingcart-styles j-m-catalog-styles j-m-product-styles-disabled j-m-facebook-styles j-m-sharebuttons-styles j-m-externalSource-styles j-m-formnew-styles j-m-callToAction-styles j-m-turbo-styles j-m-spacing-styles j-m-googleplus-styles j-m-dummy-styles j-footer-styles cc-pagemode-default cc-content-parent jqbga-container jdbga-web--color" id="page-2147754849">

<div id="cc-inner" class="cc-content-parent">

<header><div class="navigation-colors">
        <div class="tpl-topbar-wrapper">
            <div class="tpl-title-wrapper">
                <div id="cc-website-title" class="cc-single-module-element"><div id="cc-m-10956465649" class="j-module n j-header"><a href="http://osgs-kantine-site-design.jimdo.com/"><h1 class="cc-within-single-module-element j-website-title-content" id="cc-m-header-10956465649">OSG Schoonoord Kantine Website</h1></a></div></div>
            </div>
            <nav class="tpl-navigation"><div data-container="navigation"><div class="j-nav-variant-nested"><ul class="cc-nav-level-0 j-nav-level-0"><li id="cc-nav-view-2147752549" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/" data-link-title="--- Home ---">--- Home ---</a></li><li id="cc-nav-view-2147754849" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0 cc-nav-current j-nav-current jmd-nav__item--current"><a href="/login-1/" data-link-title="Login" class="cc-nav-current j-nav-current jmd-nav__link--current">Login</a></li><li id="cc-nav-view-2147754949" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/voorwaarden/" data-link-title="Voorwaarden">Voorwaarden</a></li><li id="cc-nav-view-2147755049" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/contact/" data-link-title="Contact">Contact</a></li></ul></div></div>
            </nav><div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <div id="cc-website-logo" class="cc-single-module-element"><div id="cc-m-10956474449" class="j-module n j-imageSubtitle"><div class="cc-m-image-container"><figure class="cc-imagewrapper cc-m-image-align-1">
<a href="http://osgs-kantine-site-design.jimdo.com/" target="_self"><img srcset="https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/s2080dbef3339dc21/image/i2d821423f9ea4bff/version/1456656485/image.png 184w" sizes="(min-width: 184px) 184px, 100vw" id="cc-m-imagesubtitle-image-10956474449" src="https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/s2080dbef3339dc21/image/i2d821423f9ea4bff/version/1456656485/image.png" alt="" class="" data-src-width="184" data-src-height="144"></a>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="cc-clear"></div>
</div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>

<div class="content-wrapper content-options-box cc-content-parent">
    <section class="content-options-css content-options-inner cc-content-parent"><div class="breadcrumbs breadcrumb-options">
            <div data-container="navigation"><div class="j-nav-variant-breadcrumb"><ol><li itemscope="true" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" class="cc-nav-current j-nav-current"><a href="/login-1/" data-link-title="Login" itemprop="url" class="cc-nav-current j-nav-current"><span itemprop="title">Login</span></a></li></ol></div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content_area" data-container="content">
            </div>
        <div id="content_start">

        </div>
        
        <div id="formDiv">
            <div id="form_div" runat="server" class="j-module n j-htmlCode ">
                <form>
                    Stamnummer:
                    <p></p>
                    <input class="stname"type="text" />
                    <p></p>
                    Wachtwoord:
                    <p />
                    <input class="pass" type="password" />
                    <p />
                    <asp:Button ID="Inlog_button" runat="server" Text="Button" click="Inlog_button_Click"/>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div id="cc-m-10956595049" class="j-module n j-callToAction ">
                <div class="j-calltoaction-wrapper j-calltoaction-align-1">

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </section>
</div>

<aside class="sidebar-options-box"><section class="sidebar-options-css sidebar-options-inner"><div data-container="sidebar"><div id="cc-matrix-2937969949"></div></div>
    </section></aside><footer class="footer-options"><div class="tpl-footer-wrapper">
        <div id="contentfooter" data-container="footer">

    
    

    

    <div class="copyright-footer">  <p class="pull-left"> <strong>Copyright 2016 - Hugo Woesthuis</strong></p> </div> 
</div>

    </div>
</footer><aside class="tpl-shoppingcart">
</aside>
</div>

<script> /*<![CDATA[*/ (function(){ if (!window.GoogleAnalyticsObject) { (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','_jc_tracker'); } else { window._jc_tracker = window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject]; } _jc_tracker('create', 'UA-54647672-2', { name: 'JC_TRACKER', alwaysSendReferrer: true, cookieDomain: location.hostname, cookieName: '_jc_tracker', siteSpeedSampleRate: 50, anonymizeIp: true }); var cParams = { 'page': location.hostname }; if (location.hash.indexOf('jc=') > -1) { var source = "garbled"; var passedSource = location.hash.match(/jc=([^&$]+)/); if (passedSource && passedSource[1]) { source = decodeURIComponent(passedSource[1]); } cParams = { campaignName: 'jimdo internal campaign', campaignMedium: 'link', campaignSource: source }; } _jc_tracker('JC_TRACKER.send', 'pageview', cParams); if (window.addEventListener && window.performance && performance.timing) { window.addEventListener('load', function() { if (performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart > 0) { var timeToContentLoaded = performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart - performance.timing.domLoading; _jc_tracker('JC_TRACKER.send', 'timing', 'page speed', 'time to content loaded', timeToContentLoaded); } }); } }()); /* ]]> */ </script><!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WDBL3P" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','_jimdoDataLayer','GTM-WDBL3P');
// ]]>
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->



<script id="" type="text/javascript">(function(){try{var a=Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth,window.innerWidth||0),b=Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight,window.innerHeight||0);_jc_tracker&&_jc_tracker("JC_TRACKER.set","metric1",a);_jc_tracker&&_jc_tracker("JC_TRACKER.set","metric2",b);_jc_tracker("JC_TRACKER.send","event")}catch(c){}})();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your form should have "runat =server " attribute

Comment: Yes, @AlwaysAProgrammer is right - you should add runat="server" to your form tag.

Comment: @AlwaysAProgrammer not working

Comment: You can't have multiple forms in ASPX web forms.  The page should already have one by default that is right inside the Body tag and wraps the whole page.  That's the way ASPX web forms works.  It posts the whole page back for anything.  Secondly you should be using an ASP:Button, not a runat server input element.  Further more said button has to have an ID attribute and a Name Attribute otherwise the engine can't figure out which button to tie to the server click.  Use an ASP:Button and give it an ID it will handle the name for you.

Comment: submit input does not define attribute "OnServerClick". If you want to use the submit input type, set the following attributes on the form method="post" action="<filename>.aspx"

Comment: @Ryios if I do that I will get the HttpExeption (0x80004005)

Comment: If you only want to redirect the user to another page, you could assign a Javascript handler to the OnClientClick event of an ASP.NET button and avoid submitting the form, or use a HyperLink element.

Comment: If you are getting an HttpException then you have issues overall, you are not doing something right.  Sounds like you are jumping into an ASPX project with next to no knowledge of it, IIS, or Visual Studio.  Post more overall information about the page, your IDE, and your overall process.  We need to see the top of the page to where the Page tag is and any Register and assembly tags.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I won't only redirect the user to a page, it will send some data to a SQL server

Comment: @Ryios i inserted the code

Comment: Off Topic, but you should really update this thing to use a Master Page and put your Form Runat=server tag in the master page.  You shouldn't do inline CSS either, it should be in a file and linked to with a Link element.

Comment: Your <form tag does indeed need to be runat=server.  But it should be in the master page that doesn't currently exist.  In ASP.Net WebForms the form tag is required on every page with server controls and there can only be one form on the page with the runat=server attribute.  ASP.Net forms does weird things with standard HTML, so don't go into it thinking it's like Classic ASP or PHP, it's a whole different beast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You must send the whole page in `<form>` attribute. There is no partial send in asp.Net.

2) Input element cannot reach codebehind this way. You can easily do what you want to do by using asp.Net button object instead.

Answer (score 0):

1.from should be `<form runat=server>`

2.Your `click` event  should be `onclick`.

Then it will work.

`<form runat=server>
                    Stamnummer:
                    <p></p>
                    <input class="stname"type="text" />
                    <p></p>
                    Wachtwoord:
                    <p />
                    <input class="pass" type="password" />
                    <p />
                    <asp:Button ID="Inlog_button" runat="server" Text="Button" 
                            onclick="Inlog_button_Click"/>
                </form>`